# How to show the error message with multiple error in swift?

Tags: swift, error-handling

I use the enum to create multiple error. But I don't know how to handle these errors. Now I use the `is`, `as` to handle it. I what to find a better method to do this.
For example:

```
enum URLError: Error {
    case notConnectedToInternet
    case timeout
    ...
}

enum HTTPError: Error {
    case unauthorized
    ...
}

extension UIViewController {
    func showErrorMessage(_ error: Error) {
         if let error = error as? URLError {
          // handle the URLError
         }
         if let error = error as? HTTPError {
          // handle the HTTPError
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: here's a good starting point: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html

Comment: Tks. But the article only show how to create and throw a error

Comment: ... And also how to handle and differentiate between error types with some examples

Comment: do you mean this? 
https://gist.github.com/Terriermon/662c4c7372c61fa10ffed2cbc34c198d

Comment: Yes.. your question is very open-ended. "how to handle these errors" could mean ten different things, and "how best to do this" would be subjective

Comment: Is the code for showing an error message for `URLError` very similar to the code for showing an error message for `HTTPError`? I wrote my answer thinking they are very different. But if they are very similar, maybe you can make them conform to a common protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would better if you checked the type of the error using `catch` clauses, rather than in a "god method" like `showErrorMessage`.

When you catch your error, do:

```
do {
    ...
} catch let error as URLError {
    showURLErrorMessage(error)
} catch let error as HTTPError {
    showHTTPErrorMessage(error)
} catch {
    showGenericErrorMessage(error)
}
```

Where each of the `showXXXErrorMessage` will accept a parameter of the corresponding type:

```
func showURLErrorMessage(_ error: URLError) {
    ...
}
func showHTTPErrorMessage(_ error: HTTPError) {
    ...
}
func showGenericErrorMessage(_ error: Error) {
    ...
}
```